# How do I unset an environment variable with python tox?

Tags: python, tox

I know well about `passenv` and `setenv` use on tox.ini files but I am facing a case where I want to undefine some variables so they are not included in the wildcard passenv.

Example

```
[testenv]
passenv = ANSIBLE_*

# I how do I assure that ANSIBLE_INVENTORY is not passed?
```

Answer (score 1):

To quote the docs:

> tox will take care of environment isolation for you: it will strip away all operating system environment variables not specified via `passenv`.

That is, you just do not mention the variables you don't want passed.

For `passenv`, docs say:

> You can override these variables with the `setenv` option.

Since a shell variable which is unset looks like an empty string, you can try to `setenv` to `''` all the variables you don't want to pass. It may or may not work, depending on how these variables are used by the code, because there *is* a difference between an empty env variable and an unset one.

I don't see any way to selectively unset variables in the tox docs. I would suggest to use a few wildcards weaker than `ANSIBLE_*` so that they don't let in the variables you want to stay unset.

Another solution would be to unset the variables *in the shell* that runs `tox`, so that the tox process was unable to access and pass them:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
unset ANSIBLE_KEYS_TO_KINGDOM
tox "$@"
```

Comment: Setting a variable to empty string is not the same as unsetting it. I know a huge number of cases where the tools using these will misbehave on empty vars.

Comment: @sorin: Exactly! This is detailed in the answer. Not all programs discern this (e.g. most shell scripts and Python scripts don't), but some do. The `unset` variant is the correct general solution.

Answer (score 1):

So far it seems impossible to perform an unset like this, so I raised it as a feature request at https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/1387

There is an workaround but it is so inconvenient that I do not even know if it worth mentioning:

```
command = bash -c "unset ANSIBLE_INVENTORY; <original command>"
```

As you can see, this approach does not scale at all and can make maintenance of tox.ini a real burden.